# Postgres tables reflected with SQLAlchemy not recognizing columns for Join

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to learn SQLAlchemy and I feel like I must be missing something fundamental. Hopefully, this is a straightforward error on my part and someone can show me the link to the documentation hat explains what I'm doing wrong.

I have a Postgres database running in a Docker container on my local machine. I can connect to it and export queries to Python using `psycopg2` with no issues.

I'm trying to recreate what I did using `pyscopg2` using `SQLAlchemy` but I'm having trouble when I try to join two tables. My current code looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import select

conn = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:my_password@localhost/in_votes')

metadata = MetaData(conn)

metadata.reflect(bind = conn)

pop = metadata.tables['pop']

absentee = metadata.tables['absentee']    

    
Session = sessionmaker(bind=conn)
session = Session()

session.query(pop).join(absentee, county == pop.county).all()
```

I'm trying to join the `pop` and `absentee` tables on the `county` field and I get the error:

`NameError: name 'county' is not defined`

I can view the columns in each table and loop through them to access the data.

Can someone clear this up for me and explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `session.query(pop).join(absentee, absentee.county == pop.county).all()`?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work but I did get a different error message: `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'county'`

Comment: You could try `session.query(pop).join(absentee, absentee.c.county == pop.c.county).all()`.  If that doesn't work, please [edit] the question to show the structure of the two tables.

Comment: Thank you, that was all I was missing. So, <tablename>.c.<columnname> is the preferred way to access columns in reflected tables? I assume the 'c' stands for column?

Comment: If you are using SQLAlchemy core then you usually need to access columns through the table's `c` attribute (yes it stands for columns).  If using the ORM then you access them directly from the model class.  You are using sessions, which are an ORM construct, with tables, which are from core, so bear in mind that many examples you see using `session.query` will be using ORM syntax.